# What's the song during the fight between Fumikage and Moonfish in Season 3 Episode 6?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

The song has come up a few times in *My Hero Academia* anime, but recently during Fumikage Tokoyami vs Moonfish in season 3 episode 6, starts at 5:40 and ends at 7:20.

What's that song?

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found it yet, the OST is called The Threat of Offence and Defence. It is from the 1st Season OST, here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ZNW3LB_fk).